# Layer 2 managed switch and layer 3 switch

Tags: router, layer2, networking, layer3

If you have layer 2 managed switches which have VLAN's on them, do you still need a layer 3 switch/router?

Comment: A layer-2 switch cannot send traffic between VLANs. You need a router for that, and a layer-3 switch has a router module in it, so that will work, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each VLAN is a separate data link layer segment - nodes in different segments cannot talk to each other. In order to enable communication between them, a router/gateway/layer-3 switch is required.

Comment: So what's the difference between a layer 2 managed switch and a layer 2 unmanaged switch?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33719/what-is-the-difference-between-smart-vs-managed-switch).

Answer (score 1):

Vlan is logical segmentation of network

As you said layer2 switch and having vlan configured on them . By default different vlan won't communicate to each other to enable communication between different vlan . We need to have router or layer 3 switch . Inter vlan routing is used in router to enable communication between different vlan as same as in layer3 switch also....